# Trying to reinstall grub after Windows update messed it up

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, boot-repair, grub-efi

I'm unable to enter into my Ubuntu after I updated my Windows 11. The bootloader stopped showing and the system directly boots into Windows. I tried to perform the recommended option of Boot-Repair using an Ubuntu live USB, but it wasn't successful.
The error it gave was: `Error:** **NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr)`.

Here's a link to the Boot-Repair Summary: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4xwwfKWTsw/

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic
ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi/vars': No such file or directory

Recommended repair: 

____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p7,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


/boot/efi added in nvme0n1p7/fstab
Mount nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7/boot/efi
No nvme0n1p7/boot/efi/efi/ ubuntu/mint folder

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p7/etc/default/grub

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of nvme0n1p7 ======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7 efibootmgr -v before grub install
EFI variables are not supported on this system.


chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7 uname -r
6.2.0-26-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7 efibootmgr -v after grub install
EFI variables are not supported on this system.

Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-86-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-86-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-84-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-84-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p7/boot/grub/grub.cfg

An error occurred during the repair.
Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

Locked-NVram detected.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on nvme0n1p7
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Intel Corporation from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1.24.0(1.24) from Dell Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0002,0001,0000,0003
Boot0000* UEFI RST Micron 2210S NVMe 512GB 213632787B1A     HD(1,GPT,5d2995da-c99d-41f5-8f50-4e93ebad9650,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0001* UEFI HTTPs Boot   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(000000000000,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)/Uri()N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,998f36f4-f1ff-424d-8311-985311296fda,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003* UEFI USB DISK 2.0 42265336452E601D    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,GPT,f7638048-7bf7-4ff0-a9a4-fc16aecb07ff,0x800,0x3a977c0)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi)N.....YM....R,Y.
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,5d2995da-c99d-41f5-8f50-4e93ebad9650,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................

64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
433224d074127c34064dfa0d732a9977   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
32f69782c9966aee03f44d5ec4ad6711   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p7   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p7   : isnotESP, fstab-has-bad-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p7   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: BBE3CAA2-2749-4B57-B3D9-FBEC723B30F8
              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     206847    204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    206848     239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    239616  332488703 332249088 158.4G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 332488704  333885439   1396736   682M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 333887488  569817087 235929600 112.5G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p6 569817088  589817855  20000768   9.5G Linux swap
nvme0n1p7 589817856 1000214527 410396672 195.7G Linux filesystem
Disk sda: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: E8E23585-345F-4413-BD93-898FD083BD49
      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sda1   2048 61439935 61437888 29.3G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:gpt: USB DISK 2.0:;
1:1049kB:31.5GB:31.5GB:fat32:Main Data Partition:msftdata;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Micron 2210S NVMe 512GB:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:170GB:170GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:170GB:171GB:715MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
5:171GB:292GB:121GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
6:292GB:302GB:10.2GB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
7:302GB:512GB:210GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
└─sda1      vfat     C067-5CA6                            f7638048-7bf7-4ff0-a9a4-fc16aecb07ff KUBUNTU 22_ Main Data Partition
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     D65E-0E26                            5d2995da-c99d-41f5-8f50-4e93ebad9650             EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               6415feb0-3662-4ad2-be99-c7c6060a7eef             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     001861111861074E                     33f1ad55-306d-4387-9055-1336e27e1aa8             Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     3470FE1D70FDE590                     7f10b878-255c-4b9e-9202-919f3634ed91             
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     42A8CAC0A8CAB1A9                     142a86d5-2c9f-4bb1-8989-20ba4b919569 New Volume  Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p6 swap     e32d2696-a5cf-44c7-bf27-ede0c4b73199 c8d71a02-1cc4-4592-8319-2191e7277cbc             
└─nvme0n1p7 ext4     3b2ed7ad-5c0d-47b4-bf05-e372b04bbda5 b1a4a2f3-a6f2-4f8e-8c45-15059d2d7cee             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                           Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1             62.8M  35% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3            117.2G  26% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4             89.6M  87% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5            107.8G   4% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p7             92.9G  46% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7
/dev/sda1                  25.3G  14% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 3b2ed7ad-5c0d-47b4-bf05-e372b04bbda5 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p7/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   3b2ed7ad-5c0d-47b4-bf05-e372b04bbda5
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-86-generic   3b2ed7ad-5c0d-47b4-bf05-e372b04bbda5
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-84-generic   3b2ed7ad-5c0d-47b4-bf05-e372b04bbda5
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-D65E-0E26
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p7/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=3b2ed7ad-5c0d-47b4-bf05-e372b04bbda5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=e32d2696-a5cf-44c7-bf27-ede0c4b73199 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=D65E-0E26  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

==================== nvme0n1p7/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p7: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 376.171958923 = 403.911565312  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 354.289134979 = 380.415062016  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-84-generic                 2
 376.171958923 = 403.911565312  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-86-generic                 2
 354.289134979 = 380.415062016  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 311.247066498 = 334.198992896  boot/initrd.img                                4
 286.997066498 = 308.160753664  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-84-generic              6
 311.247066498 = 334.198992896  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-86-generic              4
 286.997066498 = 308.160753664  boot/initrd.img.old                            6

=================== nvme0n1p7: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 16  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 16  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 19  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 16  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 16  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 19  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 16  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 16  2022 41_custom

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Kubuntu
Kubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
```

When I was in the *Try Ubuntu* mode, I was able to see my Ubuntu partition, but wasn't able to access my home folder as it was locked.

Comment: Showing Locked NVRAM. Locked-NVram Check UEFI settings. Windows updates may have updated UEFI also & reset to defaults.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482909 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490084
Locked NVRAM - turning on Secure boot & reset UEFI Dell XPS 9530
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490359
Locked UEFI/BIOS setting: Lenovo UEFI screen
https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Foygxuo193ui41.jpg

Comment: Thank you for your input but unfortunately, this did not work, although i was able to solve the problem by following some steps mentioned by @MAFoElffen on Ubuntu forums to which I'll provide a link https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2491460