# How do I add Ubuntu to my BIOS

Tags: boot, bios

My installation on a Dell Vostro was originally Windows and I installed Ubuntu and kept Windows for the time being. I have had problems with the BIOS on this machine. It would just stick at the Dell screen. I finally got it to respond to F12 and entered the BIOS menu. I reset the BIOS to its standard state. I guessed wrongly, that it would look for files to boot from - either Windows or Ubuntu and give me a choice. It just boot to Windows and when I enter the BIOS menu again I see that it is the only option (UEFI: VTP1TSSDI, Partition 1.

How can I tell it how to find the Ubuntu file from which to boot please?

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu should be an entry in UEFI boot menu f12, unless you installed in very old BIOS boot mode and then it would be a drive entry. My Dell with Gen 11 Intel chip is UEFI only, but still calls it BIOS settings. Lets see details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Thanks. I used the ISO file for my first ever installation of Linux on 4th October this year (so I’m  new to this - but you guessed that) and flashed it onto a USB.  I don’t know what a ppa  version is. Please tell me if you need something different. I ran “Try Ubuntu” from this as directed and the two sudo commands. The pastebin link is https://paste.Ubuntu.com/p/gHWVhFnGfX/

Comment: A ppa personal archive is another download source for software. You should only use ppa from a trusted source. But you run Boot-Repair. It shows UEFI with Secure Boot on. And two Windows entries, but neither in default boot order, and no Ubuntu entry see line 78. Ubuntu should work with Secure Boot on, but often easier just to turn it off. Your choice. You can use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub which should add a new Ubuntu UEFI entry. You may want to reorder UEFI boot entries, so preferred system is first, but only grub may boot Windows if Secure boot off & Windows fast start up off,

Comment: Thanks, I ran boot-repair. Error: NVRam is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr)

Comment: Pastebin paste.Ubuntu.com/p/yCkcFc266F/

Comment: When I first ran it, the Error message was the same but also noted that secure boot was enabled and should not be. I logged out, entered BIOS, disabled secure boot and tried again. Results above.

Comment: We are seeing more & more of Locke NVRAM issues. Some fixes, but does not seem to have jut one fix. Locked-NVram
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488426/trying-to-reinstall-grub-after-windows-update-messed-it-up & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2491460  &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482909
 Some turn Secure boot back on,some update UEFI firmware. Some find another setting in UEFI settings, separate from Secure Boot.

Comment: Thank you for these links. I see that in one of them the user mentions that he could see his Ubuntu partition using "try Ubuntu" but could not access it as it was locked. I can  see mine and it is not locked. Can I copy the file name for the boot and add it as a boot option in the BIOS? Where is the file located please?

Comment: Grub install uses efibootmgr `man lefibootmgr` to add UEFI boot entries. It is not a file on drive, but in NVRAM. Is f12 your UEFI one time boot menu? Varies by vendor. If Boot-Repair in reinstalling grub has Locked RAM issue, then I would expect efibootmgr to also have that issue. Did f2 UEFI settings show any setting that would allow your to add boot loader?

Comment: F2 or F12 takes me to Bios. Within this there is an option "add boot option" upon opening, there are three fields. Boot option name - which is blank, File system list - which is populated and File name - which allows browsing of Directories. File system list is populated by one entry (which I guess is for Windows) when the live Ubuntu usb is not present, and two entries when the usb is present. The Directories available are EFI and System Volume Information. within EFI are Microsoft, boot, Ubuntu and Dell...contd.

Comment: Within Ubuntu - grub64.efi, shimx64.efi, mmx64.efi, BOOT64.csv, grub.cfg. Within boot - fbx64.efi, mmx64.efi, bootx64.efi, bkpboot64.efi, grub64.efi. Wuithin Dell - diags_previous.xml, diags_current.xml. Within Microsoft - Boot, Recovery.

Comment: I should have added: Under boot options/filename/directory there is an option for FSO or FSI, the above data is for FSI. Under FSO the subdirectory is boot, with three files: grubx64.efi, mmx64.efi and bootx.efi

Comment: Normally the UEFI boot entry is similar to this which is my entry: `Boot0005* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,c371fe4e-a6db-4c46-b056-a4eea609f81d,0x800,0xff000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)` The long letters & numbers is the GUID of the ESP. That is auto populated by specifying the ESP. The actual boot file to select should be /EFI/Ubuntu/shimx64.efi. And label it "ubuntu". Most systems also have a fallback entry that uses /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. That is originally a copy of Windows efi boot file, bur grub install makes it a copy of shimx64.efi.  The fallback/drive entry is like the entry for flash.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you so much for all your timely help.

Answer (score 1):

To add boot entry using UEFI system settings & boot tab.
Normally the UEFI boot entry is similar to this which is my entry:

```
Boot0005* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,c371fe4e-a6db-4c46-b056-a4eea609f81d,0x800,0xff000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
```

The long letters & numbers is the GUID of the ESP. That is auto populated by specifying the ESP. The actual boot file to select should be

```
 /EFI/Ubuntu/shimx64.efi.
```

And label it "ubuntu". Most systems also have a fallback entry that uses

/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.

That is originally a copy of Windows efi boot file, bur grub install makes it a copy of shimx64.efi. The fallback/drive entry is like the entry for flash.

From your install or a live installer in live mode, you should be able to see UEFI boot entries.

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
man efibootmgr
```