# "ALERT! UUID=[...] does not exist." on a fresh Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, grub2

I have an HP 15.6 in Laptop. I tried installing Ubuntu 22.04 instead of the stock Windows 11 that came with the device. When trying to boot after the install, it stops with the following output:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=4e9c3790-267f-48df-9c0a-42a9adfee8bd does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

"cat /proc/cmdline" produces the following output:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-26-generic root=UUID=4e9c3790-267f-48df-9c0a-42a9adfee8bd ro quiet splash
```

"ls /dev | grep sd" and "ls/dev | grep mmc" produce nothing.
"blkid" produces nothing.

Booting into a Ubuntu ISO and running "sudo fdisk -l" produces this in regards to my hard drive:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 119.2 GiB, 127984992256 bytes, 31246336 sectors
Disk model: KLUDG4UHGC-B0E1
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 524288 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 8AF8F545-F1A9-437E-A9F5-6B073606B0DC

Device       Start      End  Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1      256   131327   131072   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2   131328 31246079 31114752 118.7G Linux filesystem
```

I'll note that it makes no mention of any boot drives, something my working Ubuntu laptop does.

Booted from a Ubuntu ISO I can view and mount the hard drive fine. I tried updating initramfs and grub from the mounted drive, but to no avail.

Booted from a Ubuntu ISO, running "sudo blkid" produces the following in regards to my hard drive:

```
/dev/sdb2: UUID="4e9c3790-267f-48df-9c0a-42a9adfee8bd" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e73a97de-296a-4905-9dd5-aee72da3d3a1"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="9E35-865B" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="39fc313e-fc4c-4529-add9-1be06a6177b9"
```

If I mount the hard drive and open /etc/fstab all of the UUIDs match.

Switching out the UUID in Grub's edit mode with the UUID given to me by fdisk doesn't work, as grub complains that there's "no such device".

Reinstalling Ubuntu doesn't change anything.
Reinstalling Windows 11 works fine.
Looking through my BIOS there's nothing I can see that would feasibly affect anything.
Boot-Repair doesn't help. Here's the paste from running it: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/cfgp2mN6Rn/

I'm honestly floored by this. My working Ubuntu (22.04) laptop is a similar budget HP device. Same BIOS and all, and it's never given me grief. If anyone could throw some ideas into the ring on how to get this computer working, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Update:

Tried fsck -f /dev/sd** on all partitions of my hard drive. No dice.

Comment: Use sudo on the blkid command. Look for /dev/nvme* for your disk devices.  Is there a typo on your reported "root=[uuid] (should be "root=UUID=[uuid]" where uuid should match the blkid report for your root.

Comment: It would be easier to figure this out if you didn't redact key info

Comment: @ubfan1 /dev/nvme* isn't present. All that's printed is the flashdrive I'm booting from, and my hard drive as /dev/sdb*,

cat /proc/cmdline above contained a typo. I'll fix it, but what you said is present.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I didn't think it would make a difference, but sure. I've updated the main post with the original UUIDs intact.

Comment: What is "the UUID given to me by fdisk"? The disk identifier? And can you edit in your fstab? This question is looking a lot like one posted a few days ago, that I don't think was resolved. Wondering if there is a new generic issue.

Comment: Yes, the disk identifier. I'm assuming now that's constant between disks, but I had to try everything that came to mind. Booting from an ISO and mounting the drive I can edit fstab, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Are you running commands from recovery mode? Or grub> which only have limited commands? HP often requires you to change boot device in UEFI settings, otherwise it tries to boot Windows. Lets see details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred Any command that isn't available from the (initramfs) terminal (namely sudo) I run from a recovery image. Forcing it to boot Ubuntu from my boot settings doesn't change anything. The pastebin is in the original post. Updating packages doesn't help either I'm afraid...

Comment: I would run dosfsck on ESP. Double check of sda or sdb as it looks like your flash drive is promoted to sda if plugged in on reboot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/862724/grub2-failed-to-install/86587z682#865872 Your Windows UEFI entry refers to a GUID that does not exist. See VI to add Windows UEFI entry: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win Locked ESP may be a setting in UEFI for security, separate from Secure Boot. HP Zbook 15 NVRAM locked, install issues multiple settings
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482555

Comment: @oldfred Tried running dosfsck on ESP, no dice there either. I ran boot repair again making sure it was looking at the right drive for a boot partition, and still nothing. There's no setting in the firmware for locked NVram, nor any other security settings I could find that made a difference.

Comment: A lot of locked NVRAM issues and no one solution. Some are setting in UEFI, some are issues with ESP settings, some just seem to get fixed with a variety of  changes, so not sure what worked. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488426/trying-to-reinstall-grub-after-windows-update-messed-it-up & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2491460  &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482909 Locked UEFI/BIOS setting: Lenovo UEFI screen
https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Foygxuo193ui41.jpg