Missing Ubuntu boot option entry after Windows update on Dual Boot system (SOLVED)
EDIT 2 (SOLVED): Leaving this up for any future use. I fixed my issue by running boot-repair and then logging into Windows and typing this command into powershell:
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
Original post:
Turned on my computer today and GRUB didn't pop up. Checked the BIOS boot order and the ubuntu entry was gone from there too. I believe this is due to a recent Windows Update borking the boot partition and GRUB after doing some reading on similar threads.
The usual recommendation was to run boot-repair on a live Ubuntu session, which I did, however it did not fix the issue, and I still can't see Ubuntu as an option or GRUB when booting.
Here is the pastebin I get when running the "get boot info summary" option on boot repair.
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk part_msdos fshelp fat ntfs exfat
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbia32.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/grubx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/GR/grubx64.efi /efi/GR/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/GR/shimx64.efi /efi/fedora/gcdia32.efi 
                       /efi/fedora/gcdx64.efi /efi/fedora/grubia32.efi 
                       /efi/fedora/grubx64.efi /efi/fedora/mmia32.efi 
                       /efi/fedora/mmx64.efi /efi/fedora/shim.efi 
                       /efi/fedora/shimia32.efi /efi/fedora/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/GR/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/fedora/grub.cfg /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on nvme0n1p4
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Lucienne from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 23.10, mantic, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: GLCN63WW(1.63) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0016
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0012,0013,0014,0015,0016,0018,0019
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,e4e92010-3d7a-4e36-a332-d74f7a39626e,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...5................
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(86488440-41bb-42c7-93ac-450fbf7766bf)
Boot0012* NVMe: SAMSUNG MZALQ512HBLU-00BL2              PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-25-38-D2-21-B1-0F-A5)....2.LN........
Boot0013* ATA HDD:  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot0014* ATA HDD1: VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f601)
Boot0015* ATAPI CD: VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354)
Boot0016* USB HDD: Intenso Alu Line PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x8,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x4)/USB(0,0)3.!..3.G..A.....
Boot0017  PCI LAN:  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot0018* USB FDD:  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot0019* USB CD:   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)

07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
b023680fdcebf4a4b32618450f63fdd3   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbia32.efi
39bc76ff6662f4fbe9aa116e4c997b41   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p1/Boot/grubx64.efi
4ba5a5aad43c197e9fb58b76b404d287   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p1/GR/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/GR/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/GR/shimx64.efi
483086852e971e3734d8b695f1b08ca3   nvme0n1p1/fedora/gcdia32.efi
d3d81d7094a539cefe6773ae81b44633   nvme0n1p1/fedora/gcdx64.efi
48b6080ade99a8800dc623f225bf8269   nvme0n1p1/fedora/grubia32.efi
85933e1a7b69bfacaf2a6d5bdf4197fe   nvme0n1p1/fedora/grubx64.efi
7010d05a34cbf0c3e696df6a62f56015   nvme0n1p1/fedora/mmia32.efi
bd6eccfe55c5ec7e206500ac01cb0cd4   nvme0n1p1/fedora/mmx64.efi
88a7b0e2436865122255f78aa52edaec   nvme0n1p1/fedora/shim.efi
b6410a7309a1aa9a05df02ea1954c02d   nvme0n1p1/fedora/shimia32.efi
88a7b0e2436865122255f78aa52edaec   nvme0n1p1/fedora/shimx64.efi
66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4ba5a5aad43c197e9fb58b76b404d287   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
0dddc55d593fc13c3ab3cb750e1a188a   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi
cfc91f581a0eb379f573d7bbced9061c   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
378f8a2aae778974836aea7a73116b74   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
b8796e68099026aabcebb8fcf75b21f6   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi
b6410a7309a1aa9a05df02ea1954c02d   nvme0n1p1/Boot/BOOTIA32.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p4   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: C57B7D7F-D702-4330-AD4B-0AEE5CB98F2C
             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    567296  813057987 812490692 387.4G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 813058048  996118527 183060480  87.3G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p5 996118528 1000214527   4096000     2G Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00026df2
     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 61439999 61437952 29.3G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:31.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Intenso Alu Line:;
1:1049kB:31.5GB:31.5GB:fat32::boot, lba;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:SAMSUNG MZALQ512HBLU-00BL2:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:416GB:416GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:416GB:510GB:93.7GB:ext4::;
5:510GB:512GB:2097MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
└─sda1      vfat     28A2-66BE                            00026df2-01                          UBUNTU 23_1 
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     3E9B-FBDB                            e4e92010-3d7a-4e36-a332-d74f7a39626e SYSTEM_DRV  EFI System Partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               582b8ea0-d9f1-41cf-b8a9-8098ae212890             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     CC0C9CA60C9C8D58                     c3e94c92-56ba-4849-b11e-0075160e5b74 Windows-SSD Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ext4     68fca038-6868-42f7-bb0f-485654b57fbc af0affa5-156d-44e7-b9a7-317db4a9e419             
└─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     785E9DDE5E9D958A                     1b3a27e1-db74-46c9-b6da-cff1e1352fb5 WINRE_DRV   Basic data partition

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                          Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1             194M  24% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3             102G  74% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4            29.9G  60% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5             1.1G  44% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/sda1                 24.5G  16% /cdrom
efivarfs                  92.9K  45% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1            vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3            fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4            ext4            rw,relatime,stripe=32
/dev/nvme0n1p5            fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda1                 vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

===================== nvme0n1p1/efi/GR/grub.cfg (filtered) =====================

search.fs_uuid 8ca9e11d-7fad-441b-89a5-07e374913c70 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/fedora/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=dev 1673bd3d-6e8c-4d76-a36e-6411ff80f720
set prefix=($dev)/grub2
export $prefix
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 68fca038-6868-42f7-bb0f-485654b57fbc root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p4/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   68fca038-6868-42f7-bb0f-485654b57fbc
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-3E9B-FBDB
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p4/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/68fca038-6868-42f7-bb0f-485654b57fbc / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
UUID=3E9B-FBDB  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

==================== nvme0n1p4/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p4: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 440.741222382 = 473.242284032  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 402.046146393 = 431.693762560  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 425.014892578 = 456.356265984  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic                  1
 402.046146393 = 431.693762560  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  2
 425.014892578 = 456.356265984  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 441.071285248 = 473.596686336  boot/initrd.img                                7
 435.508785248 = 467.623997440  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic               5
 441.071285248 = 473.596686336  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic               7
 435.508785248 = 467.623997440  boot/initrd.img.old                            5

=================== nvme0n1p4: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4 10:12 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Oct  2  2023 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4 10:12 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Oct  2  2023 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Oct  2  2023 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Oct  2  2023 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Sep  6  2023 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Oct  2  2023 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Oct  2  2023 41_custom

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p4,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)

Does anyone know if I should change any of the advanced options to fix my issue? I don't know too much about bootloaders to be certain what I should do. Any help is appreciated :)
EDIT: Running the default repair option gives me a "Boot successfully repaired!" message and the following pastebin. Yet still, not fixed. What other steps do I need to take?

The Locked NVRAM issue seems more common lately. It prevents adding an "ubuntu" entry into UEFI. Can you boot NVMe drive entry? It may still be copy of shim/grub not Windows. I always have a emergency boot drive. I now have an old too small for anything, but it has rEFInd on it which has saved me in past. Plus several full installs on external drives. Chroot with check for efivars: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2491460 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488426/trying-to-reinstall-grub-after-windows-update-messed-it-up

Please don't add SOLVED the header. Make an answer and accept it yourself when it becomes possible after a day.

Use Answer Your Own Question button below to answer your own question. Then accept the answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.
